# Gradle : How to declare transitive dependency

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am beginner in Gradle, using Crashlytics library in my app.  My Dependencies.Gradle is declared like following:

```
ext {
    crashlyticsVersion = '2.5.5@aar'
    presentationDependencies = 
        [
        crashlytics:"com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${crashlyticsVersion}"
        ]
}
```

In my Presentation.Gradle

```
dependencies {
    def presentationDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationDependencies
    compile presentationDependencies.crashlytics
}
```

According to Crashlytics doc this dependency has to be declared with Transtive = true. Not sure how to do this. My code follows clean architecture and design of gradle files come from there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

I don't see a reason why to over-complicate dependency declaration by using extension container and defining variables.

Comment: I know this works dependency declaration helps, the segregation of dependencies makes it easy to manager. See clean architecture:
https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/data/build.gradle